# Python code optimisation for an sql insert

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

I have the following code and I'm running it on some big data (2 hours processing time), I'm looking into CUDA for GPU acceleration, but in the mean time can anyone suggest ways to optimise the following code?

I is taking a 3D point from dataset 'T' and finding the point with the minimum distance to another point dataset 'B'

Is there any time saved by sending the result to a list first then inserting to the database table?

All suggestions welcome

```
    conn = psycopg2.connect("<details>")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    for i in range(len(B)):
        i2 = i + 1
        # point=T[i]
        point = B[i:i2]
        # print(B[i])
        # print(B[i:i2])
        disti = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(point, T, metric='euclidean').min()
        print("Base: ", end='')
        print(i, end='')
        print(" of ", end='')
        print(len(B), end='')
        print(" ", end='')
        print(disti)

        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO pc_processing.pc_dist_base_tmp (x,y,z,dist) values (%s, %s, %s, %s)""",
                    (xi[i], yi[i], zi[i], disti))
        conn.commit()

    cur.close()
```

## @@@@@@@@@@@@@@ EDIT @@@@@@@@@@@@@

Code update:

```
   conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=kap_pointcloud host=localhost user=postgres password=Gnob2009")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    disti = []

    for i in range(len(T)):
        i2 = i + 1
        point = T[i:i2]
        disti.append(scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(point, B, metric='euclidean').min())
        print("Top: " + str(i) + " of " + str(len(T)))
```

Insert code to go here once I figure out the syntax

@@@@@@@@ EDIT @@@@@@@@

The solution with a lot of help from Alex

```
   cur = conn.cursor()
      # list for accumulating  insert-params
    from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

    insert_params = []
    for i in range(len(T)):
        XA = [B[i]]
        disti = cdist(XA, XB, metric='euclidean').min()
        insert_params.append((xi[i], yi[i], zi[i], disti))
        print("Top: " + str(i) + " of " + str(len(T)))

    # Only one instruction to insert everything
    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO pc_processing.pc_dist_top_tmp (x,y,z,dist) values (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
                    insert_params)
    conn.commit()
```

For timing comparison the:

inital code took: 0:00:50.225644

Without multiline prints: 0:00:47.934012

taking commit out of the loop: 0:00:25.411207

I'm assuming the only way to make it faster is to get CUDA working?

Comment: I suppose you're overcommitting here. Can you: a) move `conn.commit` outside of loop, b) prepare data in loop and then `executemany` from prepared data, c) use bulk-loading (`COPY`) from prepared data

Comment: And `print`-s are not free. Remove them or at least make only 1 `print` instead of 7.

Comment: Thanks moving the print lines to a single lined saved 3 seconds for 8000 records, seeing as I'm using 80,000+ records that should be a 30 second+ saving. But I suspect the real savings will be in the commitment stage when communicating with the database.

Comment: Redirect to `/dev/null` will be even faster. BUT real savings will be: a) commit larger chunks of works, b) executemany, c) BULK operations

Comment: I've tried execute many `cur.executemany('insert into pc_processing.pc_dist_base_tmp(x) values (%s)', [(x,) for x in xi])` this works but if I add `...values (%s, %s)', [(x,) for x in xi], [(y,) for y in yi])` it complains about too many variables.

Comment: Try to NOT doing any `INSERT`s in your `for`-loop. Instead of inserting create a list of parameters for insert and `append` to this list on each iteration. After that you can:  a) `executemany` from this list, b) write this list to a file and use postgresql `COPY` to bulk-load from this file. Both options will be faster than RBAR("row-by-agonizing-row")`INSERT`s

Comment: I'll update my code so you can see that I've extracted the insert from the for loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188065/discussion-between-alex-yu-and-gary-nobles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Let's accumulate all suggestions from comments.

## Suggesion 1. `commit` as rare as possible, don't `print` at all

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("<details>")
cur = conn.cursor()
insert_params=[]

for i in range(len(B)):
    i2 = i + 1
    point = B[i:i2]
    disti = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(point, T, metric='euclidean').min()        
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO pc_processing.pc_dist_base_tmp (x,y,z,dist) values (%s, %s, %s, %s)""", (xi[i], yi[i], zi[i], disti))        

conn.commit() # Note that you commit only once. Be careful with **realy** big chunks of data
cur.close()
```

If you really need debug information inside your loops - use `logging`.

You will be able to turn on/off logging info when you need.

## Suggestion 2. `executemany` for rescue

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("<details>")
cur = conn.cursor()
insert_params=[] # list for accumulating  insert-params 

for i in range(len(B)):
    i2 = i + 1
    point = B[i:i2]
    disti = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(point, T, metric='euclidean').min()        
    insert_params.append((xi[i], yi[i], zi[i], disti))

# Only one instruction to insert everything
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO pc_processing.pc_dist_base_tmp (x,y,z,dist) values (%s, %s, %s, %s)", insert_params)                     
conn.commit()
cur.close()
```

## Suggestion 3. Don't use `psycopg2` at all. Use BULK operations

Instead of `cur.execute`, `conn.commit` write `csv`-file. 
And then use [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-copy.html) from created file.

BULK solution must provide ultimate performance but needs an effort to make it work.

Choose yourself what is appropriate for you - how much speed do you need.

Good luck

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 solutions

1) Try to do the single commit or commit in chunks if len(B) is very large.

2) you can prepare a list of data that you are inserting and do the bulk insert.

eg:

```
insert into pc_processing.pc_dist_base_tmp (x, y, z, dist) select * from unnest(array[1, 2, 3, 4], array[1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Comment: This works with your example but I'm trying to pass an array and it fails
        `cur.execute(
        """
        insert into pc_processing.pc_dist_base_tmp(x, y, z, dist)
        select * from unnest(xi, yi, zi, disti);
        """
        )` all arrays are the same length, it is complaining the column xi does not exist, which is not the case.

Comment: xi was a list object so I `xi =  np.asarray(xi)` but the error persists

Answer (score 1):

Try committing when the loop is finished instead of every single iteration